# Setup POST variables and the Redirect Page

Tags: php

I currently have a standard paypal form, which posts to paypal and charges an amount.  However these details can easily be modified by the user.  So, I am wondering if I can do the following:

Instead of my 'Finish & Pay' button going directly to paypal, the button's form is pointed at my website.

My website PHP code then set's up the POST variables, (address, name, amount, business, return_url etc) and then redirects the page to paypal site.

How would this be possible with PHP? So far the only code I would know to do would be using the `header()` function to redirect the page, but I don't know how to set up the POST variables.

Comment: you don't set the `POST` variables on redirect. you have to do a different request.

Comment: Damnit then! What can I do? People can just edit the `amount` field in my form that POSTs to paypal.  This is crap.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143548/paypal-security-flaw

Comment: Your going to have to post those details to paypal eventually, so just keep using your `finish & pay`. But check the order against what was paid, after returning to the site, and tell user that there is still X to pay

Comment: Is that what everyone else does? I can't believe paypal have got as big as they are with this kind of development in place.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT - This doesn't work**

Try this:

```
// Set Data
$data = array();
$data['address'] = $_POST['address'];
$data['name'] = $_POST['name'];
//  the other info ....

// Send post data as url-encoded in the header
$req = http_build_query($data);

header("method: POST\r\n");
header("Host: localhost\r\n");
header("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($req)."\r\n");
header($req."\r\n\r\n");
header("Connection: close\r\n\r\n");

header("Location: http://paypal.com/path/\r\n");
```

**INITIAL POST**

You could use curl:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://paypal.com/path/');

// Set Data
$data = array();
$data['address'] = $_POST['address'];
$data['name'] = $_POST['name'];
//  the other info ....

// Set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Execute
$page = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: But that will only get the result surely, and not redirect the user to the paypal page?

Comment: On the redirect page the send data must be shown to the user?

Comment: How do I build the variable `$data` ?

Comment: `$data` is a variable array of items you want to send to paypal, after that is converted to http query using `http_build_query` and added into header.

Comment: have you tested this? I am getting server errors `Moved Temporarily`.

Comment: I will redefine my answer, wait a sec please

Comment: Until now the redirect takes place but the post data is not send at redirect and I don't understand way

Comment: It seems that is not a easy task to send post data without a HTTP client so my last answer edit doesn't work :(, I will edit it.